# SvelteKit: disable SSR

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

I made an app in Svelte and now I wanted to port it to SvelteKit. My app uses `window` and `document` objects, but those aren't available in SSR. Firstly, it threw `ReferenceError: window is not defined`, but I fixed that by checking if the app is running in the browser. But because of that, my app is not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable server-side rendering from your [`handle`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle) hook, defined in `src/hooks.js`:

```js
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    return resolve(event, { ssr: false });
}
```

It's even possible to do it conditionally, usually by inspecting `event` and making your decision per-request.

---

If your use-case requires everything to happen client-side anyway, disabling SSR makes sense. But do note that disabling it strictly because of some browser-only code *is not recommended* — in that case, it's usually better to execute code conditionally with `browser` checks and dynamic imports for client-side only dependencies. I'd explore why your app stopped working before jumping to disabling SSR.

Comment: May be I'm missing some setting, but `browser` is always `false`. I'm reading it under `load` of `__layout.svelte`.

Comment: And I'm running `dev`.

Comment: See the other answer for more recent versions

Answer (score 42):

The previous answer does no longer work because of changes in SvelteKit. See the PR for more information: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/6197 and also the documentation: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options

Basically now you disable SSR on a per page/layout level, so instead of in src/hooks.server.js (yes, hooks.js was also separated into client as server with the addition of client side hooks.)

```js
export function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  return resolve(event, { 
    ssr: false
  });
```

You now do

```js
// src/routes/+layout.js
export const ssr = false;
```

Make sure to put the line above in `+layout.js` and not `+layout.svelte`

Comment: I note that `vite` still tries to make a "ssr bundle" when building that seems to build empty .js files...
And I have not found a way to stop vite from doing that in order to speed up `vite build`

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable ssr in the svelte.config.js file. See [svelte configuration](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration) to see the options. Set prerender enabled = false to disable prerendering altogether throughout the app.

Comment: They are different concepts. You can have prerendering disabled and still do SSR.